# How to make event for specific date?

Tags: iphone

Where event detail should store?How to make alarm for specific event that i don't know.Please help with code or give link for that type of example.
Thank in Advance.

Comment: you can use local notifications to fire an alert for a particular event at a particular date. OR if you dont know the exact date you can use APNS and deliver a push notification from your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a reminder for the event in the iPhone pro grammatically for the future date. This is the sample project which will help you to schedule a event in iPhone progrmmatically. Check this Link. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: It's very useful.But i want to display that in calendar date box for that specific date.How it can be done?

Comment: Mark the event for a particular date. Then run it in the device because simulator does not contain calender. Then check your calender app in iPhone device. :)

Comment: But i have to make calendar programticaly and then add event in it.

Comment: Don't you want to use iPhone's Calender?

Comment: i have to make it programaticalyy

Answer (score 2):

You can use local notifications, here is some sample code for scheduling that.

```
- (void)scheduleNotification {

    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    //notification for 3 days
    notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60.0f*60.0f*24.0f*3.0f sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.alertBody = @"We've missed you!";
    notif.alertAction = @"PLAY";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

}
```